# How do you store values with repeating values in a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I'm trying to create a sort of quiz using android and to do so I'm storing the topics and the questions in a sqlite database, now my problem is that a topic can have more than one question and a question can apply to more than one topic how would I put this into a database any help would be a appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need three different tables. One for your Topics, one for your Questions, and one where you store the ID of the question and topic, so multiple can be linked together.

like you have topics: 1: food, 2: cars, 3: animals. 
questions: 1: what kind of car does a cat drive? 2: what kind of food does a dog eat?

and to link them in the third table you would have:

```
topic_id | question_id
2        | 1
3        | 1
1        | 2
3        | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping table holding both the question and answer Id´s, so 3 tables needed.

Say you have the table "Questions":

```
Question 1 with Id 1
Question 2 with Id 2
Question 3 with Id 3
```

Another table "Answers":

```
Answer 1 With Id 1
Answer 2 with Id 2
```

Lets say Question 1 can have both of the answers, you need to relate them with table "QuestionsAnswers" with 2 columns, one holding the Id of the question and one holding the Id of the answer:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[QuestionsAnswers](
[QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[AnswerId] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Lets simplify this and make 5 relations:

```
QuestionId | AnswerId 
1          | 1
2          | 1
2          | 2
3          | 2
1          | 2
```

answer 2 relates to question 1, 2 and 3

question 2 relates to Answer 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Using the third normal form [[see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)] you'd do something like the following:

You have 3 tables. Your table_categories, table_questions and a third table, representing the m-to-n-relationships between those two.
This is achieved by simply creating a row for each 1-to-1-realtionship, seen as follows.

```
table_categories
_______________________________________
id       name

1       "culture"
2       "history"
...
42      "animals"


table_questions
_______________________________________
id       name

1       "Which fo the following is not a member of the EU?"
2       "When was the last FIFA world cup in Europe?"
...
42      "Who was Jimmy Hendrix?"


table_question_categories
_______________________________________
id      fk_id_question    fk_id_category

1       4                 5
2       4                 37
...
42      42                5
```